# uploadig image in base64 using http client android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, http, android-studio

i have a probleme in this function ,this code is running in background to upload image taken by camera and converted to base 46, i have some errors .
see this image :
[image: android studio error]

```
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        return "Success";

    }
```

please help me
sorry for the grammar

Comment: Please post all code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can resolve the probleme by include the library in gradle

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```